# How to get a reference to the constructor of a generic class with types specified?

Tags: generics, typescript, constructor

I have a generic class defined as such.

```
class KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
{
    public Key: TKey = null;
    public Value: TValue = null;
}
```

How can I get the specific constructor that creates (as an example) the `KeyValuePair<String, Number>` object?

Edit:

I know I can create the `KeyValuePair<String, Number>` object just by calling `let x = new KeyValuePair<String, Number>()` However, I am trying to get a reference to the constructor function so that I can instantiate the object from that function; like so, in non-working code:

```
let ctorPrimitive = String;
console.log(new ctorPrimitive()); // works
let ctorGeneric = KeyValuePair<String, Number>; // <-- error
console.log(new ctorGeneric()); // does not work
```

Comment: you need to do `let ctorGeneric: { new(): KeyValuePair<String, Number> } = KeyValuePair;` or like in my answer have a type which defines the `KeyValuePair` ctor

Comment: You answered the question I posed perfectly!  However, I believe my question stemmed from my flawed understanding of TypeScript generic classes...

Comment: If anyone is interested, my follow-on question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694076/curried-constructor-of-generic-class).  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
class KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> {
    public Key: TKey = null;
    public Value: TValue = null;
}

let ctor = KeyValuePair;
let pair = new ctor();
```

Will get you a `ctor` of type `KeyValuePair` and `pair` of type `KeyValuePair<{}, {}>`.

But this:

```
type KeyValuePairConstructor<TKey, TValue> = {
    new(): KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>;
}

let ctor2: KeyValuePairConstructor<string, number> = KeyValuePair;
let pair2 = new ctor2();
```

Will get you a `ctor2` of type `KeyValuePairConstructor<string, number>` and `pair2` of type `KeyValuePair<string, number>`.

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20KeyValuePair%3CTKey%2C%20TValue%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20Key%3A%20TKey%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%09public%20Value%3A%20TValue%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20ctor%20%3D%20KeyValuePair%3B%0D%0Alet%20pair%20%3D%20new%20ctor()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20KeyValuePairConstructor%3CTKey%2C%20TValue%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09new()%3A%20KeyValuePair%3CTKey%2C%20TValue%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20ctor2%3A%20KeyValuePairConstructor%3Cstring%2C%20number%3E%20%3D%20KeyValuePair%3B%0D%0Alet%20pair2%20%3D%20new%20ctor2()%3B))

Answer (score 1):

Just define a constructor in your class using generic types:

```
class KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> {
  public key: TKey = null
  public value: TValue = null
  constructor(aKey: TKey, aValue: TValue) {
    this.key = akey
    this.value = aValue
  }
}
```

Now, define a new object with your specific type

```
// note we are using string and number instead of String and Number
let a = new KeyValuePair<string, number>('life', 42)
a.key
// => 'life'
a.value
// => 42
```

Even better, you could omit the type declaration for `KeyValuePair`:

```
// typescript knows a is a KeyValuePair<string, number>
let a = new KeyValuePair('life', 42)
```

Another example:

```
// b: KeyValuePair<Object, boolean>
let b = new KeyValuePair({}, true)
a.key
// => {}
a.value
// => true
```

*** UPDATED ***

> I am trying to get a reference to the constructor function so that I can instantiate the object from that function

This is working fine for me:

```
let KeyValuePairConstructor = KeyValuePair
// => KeyValuePairConstructor: typeof KeyValuePair
let a = new KeyValuePairConstructor('life', 42)
// => a: KeyValuePair<string, numer>
let b = new KeyValuePairConstructor({}, true)
// => b: KeyValuePair<{}, boolean>
```

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't answer my question because I would like a reference to the KeyVauePair<String, Number> constructor.  Edited my question to be clearer.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, your example works but I need a function that does not need to be provided the generic types because I intend to use it to deserialize json.

Comment: Please, develop that question. What do you need?

Comment: If you're interested, my follow-on question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38694076/curried-constructor-of-generic-class).  Thank you!