# Curried constructor of generic class

Tags: typescript, constructor, currying

Let me preface this by saying that I am not sure if this is possible.

I am trying to obtain a constructor function that can be invoked with new that takes no parameters that calls a generic class's constructor that does take parameters.  Like so:

```
class SimpleFoo {
    public Key: String = null;
}

class GenericFoo<T> {
    public Key: T = null;
    constructor(private type: { new (): T }) {
        this.Key = new this.type();
    }
}

let simpleCtor: { new (): SimpleFoo } = SimpleFoo; // works
let simpleObj = new simpleCtor();

let genericCtor: { new (): GenericFoo<String> } = GenericFoo<String>(String); // <-- non-working code -- how to curry String parameter?
let genericObj = new genericCtor(); // this is how I wish to get a new object, no parameters involved
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but this seems to work:

```
type TypeConstructor<T> = { new (): T };

class GenericFoo<T> {
    public Key: T = null;
    constructor(private type: TypeConstructor<T>) {
        this.Key = new this.type();
    }
}

let genericCtor: { new (type: TypeConstructor<String>): GenericFoo<String> } = GenericFoo;
let genericObj = new genericCtor(String);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20TypeConstructor%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20new%20()%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20GenericFoo%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20Key%3A%20T%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20type%3A%20TypeConstructor%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.Key%20%3D%20new%20this.type()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20genericCtor%3A%20%7B%20new%20(type%3A%20TypeConstructor%3CString%3E)%3A%20GenericFoo%3CString%3E%20%7D%20%3D%20GenericFoo%3B%0D%0Alet%20genericObj%20%3D%20new%20genericCtor(String)%3B))

---

#### Edit

If you don't want to pass the type when calling the ctor then you can bind the ctor to the wanted type and then call that bound ctor:

```
type BoundGenericFooConstructor<T> = { new(): GenericFoo<T> }

let genericCtor: BoundGenericFooConstructor<String> = GenericFoo.bind(null, String);
let genericObj = new genericCtor();
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20TypeConstructor%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20new%20()%3A%20T%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20GenericFoo%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20Key%3A%20T%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20type%3A%20TypeConstructor%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.Key%20%3D%20new%20this.type()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20BoundGenericFooConstructor%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20new()%3A%20GenericFoo%3CT%3E%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20genericCtor%3A%20BoundGenericFooConstructor%3CString%3E%20%3D%20GenericFoo.bind(null%2C%20String)%3B%0D%0Alet%20genericObj%20%3D%20new%20genericCtor()%3B))

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you.